# Problem with compiling by G++: why 5/18 returns zero?

Tags: g++

I have spot an interesting problem in G++:

when I use sin(50*3.14/180) I get something about 0.766,
however sin(5/18*3.24) gives me 0.000.

Isn't it exacly the same thing? Did anyone spot it before?

Thanks in advance for your answer.

Comment: This is not specific to g++, it's a question about C++ that applies with any compiler, so we can close this as off-topic.

Answer (score 2):

That has nothing to do with Ubuntu, but...

The reason is that the expression `5/18*3.24` is compiled (in this case precalculated, but alas, the result is the same) as `(5/18)*3.24`, and interpreted left-to-right.

Now, `(5/18)` is an operation between two integers, and returns the integer division between 5 and 18, which is 0 (with remainder 5, but you didn't ask for that). When you multiply 0 and 3.14, the operation is mixed, so `(int)0` is promoted to `(double)0.0` and the result is, well, `0.0` -- as expected.

In the other case, `50*3.14/180`, firstly `50*3.14` is computed; `(int)50` is promoted to `(double)50.0` and all is well.

Moral: **always** use the correct format for constants. `5` means `(int)5`, `5.0` means `(double)5.0`, `5L` means `(long int)5`, `09` means you don't know C/C++...

PS as a side note, this behavior is one of the big changes from python2 to python3. Search the net for `from __future__ import division`  if you are curious.

Comment: I thought it had something to do to with G++ directly, that's why I asked here. However, now I see it's my bad -- I forgot about integers division rules.
Thank you a lot for your thorough answer.